# Powershell Script to archive files over 1 day

Tags: powershell

I am looking for a script that can ignore the timing and utilise just the date to move files after 1 day, so yesterday, to an archive folder.

My knowledge of powershell is not great so any advice on how i can do this would be great.

Everyday i run a script that generates a .txt report which has a filename .....2022 01 02 (The filename ends with the date) so would like to add some extra lines that archives the .txts that were created yesterday to an archive folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[datetime]` type has a `Date` property that gives you the date at midnight, thereby allowing you to compare dates without taking the time component into account:

```
# Construct datetime value describing yesterday at midnight
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date

# Filter files based on date of the `CreationTime` property
$filesCreatedYesterday = Get-ChildItem -Path .\path\to\folder -File |Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date -eq $yesterday }
```

`$filesCreatedYesterday` will now contain the files created yesterday

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the reply, i tried what you mentioned but when i run it nothing happens; This is the script i added                                                  
 # Construct datetime value describing yesterday at midnight
$yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date

# Filter files based on date of the `CreationTime` property
$filesCreatedYesterday = Get-ChildItem -Path .\path\to\folder -File |Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date -eq $yesterday }|Move-item -Destination $Destination

Comment: @gelegeta That would indicate that no files created yesterday was found in the folder at `.\path\to\folder`. In addition: make sure you add `-PassThru` to the call to `Move-Item` if you want to store the moved files in `$filesCreatedYesterday` afterwards - `Move-Item` doesn't output anything by default

Comment: I changed creation time to lastwritetime as realised my problem here was the date which has now worked so thank you very much for your help with this +1

Comment: Where would i add the -PassThru sorry

Comment: That's great, you're welcome @gelegeta! To make `Move-Item` pass the moved item back to the caller: `... |Move-Item -Destination $Destination -PassThru`